# Can't click search box in browsers other than Firefox

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the following search: http://www.technabled.com/2009/03/how-to-build-animated-ajax-search-with.html

I'm able to click inside the search box and type stuff in Firefox, but not Chrome. I've tested this on a friend's computer and it doesn't work for him either.

edit: just tested it with IE9 and it doesn't work with that either.

edit2: just tested it on another computer with Firefox and it does not work. I'm thinking the problem must be because I'm hosting the website on my computer (my friend was doing the same). How do I make it not do this?

Comment: What can I do to get it to work in Chrome too?

Comment: My code is exactly the same as is on that website

Comment: @A.J. that links demo does not open

Comment: @OMTheEternity the demo on their website 404s

Comment: **It works both in CHROME and IE** There is something else causing the problem.